# How to know if sockaddr_storage usage at runtime

Tags: c, sockets

A runtime I'ld like to to know if an stack defined struct sockaddr_storage was assigned to any IP address (IPv4 or IPv6)

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you are trying to do?  (The answer is probably either "just use getnameinfo" or "that's the wrong question to be asking" but without more information that's all I can give you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `ss_family` field.  It will be `AF_INET` for an IPv4 address, or `AF_INET6` for an IPv6 address.  You can then type-cast the `sockaddr_storage` accordingly to either `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` in order to access the `sockaddr_in::sin_addr` or `sockaddr_in6::sin6_addr` field, respectively, to make sure it is not set to zeros.

Comment: Yes cheking that is not zeros (after beeing memset to 0 at startup) seams the most ragionable way to. Thanks